# Key stuck on Laptop

Tags: keyboard

My <kbd>E</kbd> key was not working so I hit it a bit harder physically and now it seems to be completely stuck. The physical key doesn't seem to be stuck as it still travels and clicks, but when I use the computer the <kbd>E</kbd> key seems to be constantly pressed. For example, when I open a Word document it just starts typing `e`. How can I fix this problem?

My computer is a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 13 with Windows 8.

Comment: It's probably not virtually stuck at all. It's probably physically stuck. You have to unstick it or replace it, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to jiggle it free or it is damaged beyond repair.  I would imagine if you try and fix it yourself you will invalidate any warranty you have.

Probably what actually happened there was some debris or crumb of sandwich under the key stopping it from working properly.  Your hard press has mashed it ontop of the contact.

You could try compressed air in the area - try from all sides.  That might blow it away.  Next step is some 99.99% alcohol or contact cleaner but you have to know what you are doing with that.  Personally at his point I'd be willing to lift the key.  On laptops they can be very fiddly and delicate, so unless you are experienced in such things I would take it to someone who knows.  Probably an independent won't charge you as much as a chain for a trivial task like this.